# Does libpurple media api require pidgin UI to launch video screen?

Tags: pidgin, libpurple

Does lipurple media API require Pidgin UI to launch video screen? Without pidgin UI just by using libpurple backend media API's can we launch video screen?

Answer (score 0):

As it currently stands, libpurple handles the protocol actions. libpurple and Pidgin use gstreamer for the actual video leg work by using gstreamer to render/overlay onto a gtk widget in Pidgin.

In theory you could then create a client for libpurple that pipes the video to a file or anything you decided to code.